# I want to replace a entire String with new value using String replaceAll method in Java

Tags: java

```
String x = "Welcome to Java World";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(".*","JAVA"));
Actual Output = "JAVAJAVA" .
Excepted Output = "JAVA".
```

Can anybody help why it replace like this . ".*" all characters in a original string and replace this with "JAVA" . Why this returns "JAVAJAVA" .

Comment: Could you try ".+" as the regex? Maybe the matching considers the empty String a substring of any String, and then the actual content of the String as a second substring, thus replacing twice? More of a shot in the dark than anything though.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your regular expression can match 0 to all characters. First, it matches the entire string `"Welcome to Java World"`, then it matches the end of the string `""`, replacing both with `"JAVA"`.

To make this work how you expect it, you have a couple options.

```
String x = "Welcome to Java World";
System.out.println(x.replaceAll(".+","JAVA"));
```

Notice the + instead of the *, this means 1 or many, so the end won't be matched.

or

```
String x = "Welcome to Java World";
System.out.println(x.replaceFirst(".*","JAVA"));
```

This will only replace the entire string with `"JAVA"`, the empty end of the string won't be replaced.

Comment: +1, do you maybe know a link where this (I mean how, where and why every String contains the empty substring) is explained in detail? It is somewhat surprising, though not difficult to understand.

Comment: I think the most clear location for this type of thing is the [source itself](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8-b132/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#Matcher.replaceAll%28java.lang.String%29). It will take some poking around that class to really understand what is going on, but that is [the best way](http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/) to really understand.

Answer (score 2):

why using "replaceAll" and not "="?
Strings are immutable in java

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `replaceAll` for your mission. The exact same semantics are achieved by simply stating

```
System.out.println("JAVA");
```

Since `String` is immutable in Java, you cannot avoid getting a new object.

Comment: Not really relevant to the question since this is about regex, not about how to have a String contain the content he wants.

Comment: I'm not sure it's about regex. The question didn't motivate it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the below format
x.replaceAll(".*\z", "JAVA");

As .* will match till before the end of string and \z will match the end of string character.